# ExecutorService not terminating in time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an ExecutorService that runs a few threads.

What I am trying to accomplish is to execute, and then wait for all threads to terminate. To give you more background, every `thread1` connects to a website.

This is what I came up with:

```
public static void terminateExecutor(ExecutorService taskExecutor) {

        taskExecutor.shutdown();
        try {
          taskExecutor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Some tasks were interrupted!"); //This gets printed
        }
    }
```

Now, strangely enough, the main thread that uses the ExecutorService terminates, but the `thread1`s in it don't.

I noticed this because `thread1` threw an error (the main thread at this point was already dead) telling me that it didn't find the URL specified (so I guess it's something related to connections).

Is it possible that `awaitTermination` doesn't terminate the `thread1` because its trying (and retrying it seems) to connect to an invalid link?

I cannot stop the `thread1` in any other way (or at least to my knowledge I can't), because there isn't any kind of loop.

EDIT:

I get `thread1` by creating a new class and feeding it to the executor.

```
for (....)
    {

        String urlToVisit = globalUrl + links.get(i);
        Thread thread1 = new MagicalThread(urlToVisit, 2).getThread();
        executor.execute(thread1);

    }
    terminateExecutor(executor.getExecutor());
```

Comment: 1) Where is `thread1`? 2) Why should the interruption message get printed? 3) I'll bet you'll find that [`awaitTermination`'s return value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) tells you something relevant.

Comment: @AndyTurner thread1 literally connects to a website, if an error was thrown it prints "hey, this link ... didn't work!". The interruption message should not get printed, thought someone might ask about it being printed so I added the comment.

Comment: Please show how you obtain "`thread1`": you don't have access directly to the thread on which a `Runnable` is run by the `ExecutorService`. Maybe you declare it as a `Thread`, but it's actually being used as a `Runnable`, and the fact it's a `Thread` isn't relevant because it's run on one of the `ExecutorService`'s internal threads.

Comment: ...and how is `MagicalThread` declared? And what is `executor` if you can call `executor.executor()` (looks like an `ExecutorService`), but calling `terminateExecutor(executor.getExecutor())` (looks like something which *has* an `ExecutorService`).

Comment: @AndyTurner Alright, the `MagicalThread` implemented runnable, and was not a thread. I quickly changed that, though it still doesn't stop. Yes, executor is a class made by me, that uses an ExecutorService to do his stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executor uses interruption to let the threads know it's time to quit. If your tasks are using blocking I/O then they will be blocked and can't check the interrupt flag. There is no ability for the blocked task to respond to the interruption in the way that happens with sleep or wait, where interruption causes the threads to wake up and throw an InterruptedException.

If you set a timeout on the socket then, once the socket times out, the task can check for interruption. Also you can have the task respond to interrupt by closing the  socket.  See https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html

Be aware that implementing this in a threadpool is more involved than in the example given in the linked article. Nothing about the executor lets the pool call methods on a task besides run. One way to do it would be to put a reference to the socket in a ThreadLocal. Then you could make a ThreadFactory for the pool to use to subclass Thread with a method that overrides the interrupt method on the thread to get the socket from the ThreadLocal and close it.

Comment: That makes sense. I wondered why threads that were attempting to connect didn't interrupt. Although I rewrote the whole thing to get it working, this is the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) (emphasis mine):

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution **after a shutdown request**

You need to call `shutdown()` before calling `awaitTermination`, otherwise it does nothing meaningful.

Comment: Tried it now. Nothing changes.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to provide more details about the tasks that are running at the time.

Answer (score 0):

When

```
taskExecutor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

returns, it doesn't guarantee that the `ExecutorService` has terminated. Look at its [return value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> [Returns] true if this executor terminated and false if the timeout elapsed before termination

You don't check this value, but I'll bet it's returning false if the thing you're running in the `ExecutorService` is still running.